# Access to excel file via microsoft graph on android

Tags: android, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to make an app for my organization which manages its onedrive files via an android app

I would like the manager of the app to maintain the app via a simple excel file which is located on my onedrive to which he will have write access and the rest of the users will have read access only. In other words, i need the app to be able to get the JSON representation of a selected excel file on my onedrive

i downloaded the "active-directory-android-native-v2-master" android sample and run it after obtaining an app ID and it worked correctly while getting the JSON response by executing the next MSGRAPH_URL constant

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
```

Now, i guess that to get my excel JSON, i  just need to modify the MSGRAPH_URL to the correct URL but i am getting very strange 404 errors when looking on the debug console (and the app seems to be stuck)

I tried modifying the app permissions via the microsoft app settings screen but with no success.

So the question is,
lets say the file i want to access is the one at the below link. What should be the correct MSGRAPH_URL constant and do i need to modify anything else? Also, is there a site or something that converts such a link to the correct graph.microsoft link?

[excel file](https://gilcarltd-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/ran_c_gil-car_co_il/Eabkxa2md3JEsW0qQEuYRK4Bw95EzoS0d-QFBstwkxNg6A?e=knZiJL)

Answer (score 0):

According to your descriptions, I assume you want to get the excel file by the Graph API and then modify them.

We can use following steps:

1. We can modify the permissions at [this site](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/?referrer=https:%2F%2Fdeveloper.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fgraph%2Fdocs%2Fconcepts%2Foverview#/appList). According to [this document](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_list_children#permissions), we should granted permission to 'Files.Read, Files.ReadWrite, Files.Read.All, Files.ReadWrite.All, Sites.Read.All, Sites.ReadWrite.All'.
2. Then use this API: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children' to get the file on your OneDrive.
   This API will return all the file on your OneDrive, you can find the excel file in the return. The result will be somthing like this:'

   "id": "{The Id for the Excel File }",
   "lastModifiedDateTime": "2018-09-03T06:05:59Z",
   "name": "Book.xlsx",
   "webUrl": "{The WebUrl for the Excel File }",
   "cTag": "\"c:{94047B18-87D4-40A6-82C8-B0A0AE2344D5},9\"",
   "size": 8252,

Now we can refer to this document to get the worksheet and use [the following Docs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/worksheet_get) to modify the Worksheet.

Comment: Not sure why i struggle so much with this. I got the ID, added all the permissions (and more). I can access the required file via the [graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#) but on the sample active-directory app it returns 404 response. I am not sure but the issue might be related to the fact that <https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children> returns on the app only {"@odata.context":"https:\/\/graph.microsoft.com\/v1.0\/$metadata#users('b051ee14-7e46-4aa0-ae85-78d71bae8939')\/drive\/root\/children","value":[]} instead of the onedrive items

Comment: As the response you posted, your root site does not have any item. You can add some items and try again